# R fast AUC function for non-binary dependent variable

Tags: r, roc

I'm trying to calculate the `AUC` for a large-ish data set and having trouble finding one that both handles values that aren't just 0's or 1's and works reasonably quickly.

So far I've tried the `ROCR` package, but it only handles 0's and 1's and the `pROC` package will give me an answer but could take 5-10 minutes to calculate 1 million rows.

As a note all of my values fall between 0 - 1 but are not necessarily 1 or 0.

EDIT: both the answers and predictions fall between 0 - 1.

Any suggestions?

EDIT2:

`ROCR` can deal with situations like this:

```
Ex.1
actual   prediction
  1         0
  1         1
  0         1
  0         1 
  1         0
```

or like this:

```
Ex.2
actual   prediction
  1         .25
  1         .1
  0         .9
  0         .01
  1         .88
```

but NOT situations like this:

```
Ex.3
actual   prediction
  .2         .25
  .6         .1
  .98        .9
  .05        .01
  .72        .88
```

`pROC` can deal with Ex.3 but it takes a very long time to compute.  I'm hoping that there's a faster implementation for a situation like Ex.3.

Comment: Data. We need an example. The terms "answers" and "predictions" are too vague, as is the request for something better than a method that "handles only 1's and 0's".

Comment: @DWin: I've added some examples above.  Let me know if they help flesh things out a bit.  Sorry for the lack of detail.

Comment: What is an 'actual' of 0.2? Is this grouped data?

Comment: @DWin: Yes, it's grouped.  It's % click thru rate on a web advertisement.  So for ad 'x' an actual of .2 means it was shown 10x and clicked on 2x or something like that.

Comment: So you should be making calibration plots instead of ROC's. Or you should be using weighting and `cumsum` to recast the data in a form from which an ROC can be calculated. The examples remain incomplete because they have no counts from which the proportions are derived.

Comment: @DWin: yes, this grouping step looses information, which makes the whole rest of the analysis ambiguous, because you do not know any longer of the 0.2 actual click-through (1st row) did coincide with the .25 predicted click-through (and we don't know the exact meaning of the prediction: is it the average of n hardened (0/1) predictions, or is it a single, continuous predition.

Comment: So you are saying you'd need the numbers broken down to something like 20 clicks and 100 serves instead of .20 to calculate an auc?

Comment: pROC is not going to deal with Ex. 3. Or let's put it differently: it's going to give you a result that's not at all what you would expect. ROC analysis is by definition aimed at binary classification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So far I've tried the ROCR package, but it only handles 0's and 1's

Are you talking about the reference class memberships or the predicted class memberships?
The latter can be between 0 and 1 in ROCR, have a look at its example data set `ROCR.simple`.

If your reference is in [0, 1], you could have a look at (disclaimer: my) package softclassval. You'd have to construct the ROC/AUC from sensitivity and specificity calculations, though. So unless you think of an optimized algorithm (as ROCR developers did), it'll probably take long, too. In that case you'll also have to think what exactly sensitivity and specificity should mean, as this is ambiguous with reference memberships in (0, 1).

**Update after clarification of the question**

You need to be aware that grouping the reference or actual together looses information. E.g., if you have actual = 0.5 and prediction = 0.8, what is that supposed to mean? Suppose these values were really actual = 5/10 and prediction = 5/10.
By summarizing the 10 tests into two numbers, you loose the information whether the *same* 5 out of the 10 were meant or not. Without this, actual = 5/10 and prediction = 8/10 is consistent with anything between 30 % and 70 % correct recognition!

Here's an illustration where the sensitivity is discussed (i.e. correct recognition e.g. of click-through):

[image: soft and]

You can find the whole poster and two presentaions discussing such issues at [softclassval.r-forge.r-project.org](http://softclassval.r-forge.r-project.org/#About%20softclassval), section "About softclassval".

Going on with these thoughts, weighted versions of mean absolute, mean squared, root mean squared etc. errors can be used as well.

However, all those different ways to express of the same performance characteristic of the model  (e.g. sensitivity = % correct recognitions of actual click-through events) do have a different meaning, and while they coincide with the usual calculation in unambiguous reference and prediction situations, they will react differently with ambiguous reference / partial reference class membership.

Note also, as you use continuous values in [0, 1] for both reference/actual and prediction, the whole test will be condensed into one point (not a line!) in the ROC or specificity-sensitivity plot.

**Bottom line:** the grouping of the data gets you in trouble here. So if you could somehow get the information on the single clicks, go and get it!

Comment: Thanks that actually helps me realize I didn't really understand the problem myself. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 1):

Can you use other error measures for assessing method performance? (e.g. Mean Absolute Error, Root Mean Square Error)?

This post might also help you out, but if you have different numbers of classes for observed and predicted values, then you might run into some issues.

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-September/172537.html

Comment: *(according to the updated question, the code behind the link won't help as it needs the usual "hard" (i.e. {0, 1}) class memberships)*,  MAE, MSE (Brier score for classification) and RMSE can be used, see my answer.